# What are the sorting algorithms for blocks that contain integers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

- The block size is 2 KB and has 512 4-byte integers.
- The integers within a block must be sorted in ascending order **within the block** and also **when all the blocks are joined together**.(All the integers in the nth block must be less than all the integers in the n+1th block.)
- (Minor information, this issue may not be important in determining the algorithm.) The blocks I want to sort are not in a row in a single file. ex) Only the 1st, 5th, 8th, and 13th blocks should be imported and sorted.

There are three main ways I thought of it.

1. Bubble sort application: Place two blocks in memory and combine to perform an alignment. Write a block with smaller integers to disk (the block preceding it in ascending order) and read the next block into memory and repeat the same process. Time complexity is O(N^2).
2. external sort: I was going to try an algorithm like K-way merge sort, but I don't think this algorithm will guarantee an ascending order of integers across the block.
3. Read the entire block into memory and sort it: In the test data, the sum of the sizes of all the blocks you wanted to sort was as small as 40 KB, so I read all the blocks into memory, put them together, and then sort them. However, this method is difficult to apply if the sum of the sizes of all the blocks is large.